# Java 8 Lambda Sort is not getting called

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list of data. I would like to sort using a custom comparator. I have following code but it is not getting executed. Could you please let me know what is wrong.

I tried with allACFs data type as `java.util.Collection`.

```
List<Interface> allACFs =  (List<Interface>) SearchUtil.seacrh(individualiterator, SearchUtil.startswith("type.code", "ACF"));

allACFs.stream().sorted(new Comparator<Interface>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Interface o1, Interface o2) {
        System.out.println(o1.getType().getCode()+" : "+o2.getType().getCode()+" > "+o1.getType().getCode().compareTo(o2.getType().getCode()));
        return o1.getType().getCode().compareTo(o2.getType().getCode());
    }
});
```

Comment: `Stream.sorted()` is an [intermediate  operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps); it doesn't modify the underlying list. Just do `allACFs.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getType().getCode()));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom comparator is not being called because you did not request any items from the stream. Therefore, sorting operation is *deferred* until you want to harvest the results of sorting.

If you want to force the call, invoke `collect(Collectors.toList())` on the stream:

```
List<Interface> list = allACFs.stream().sorted(new Comparator<Interface>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Interface o1, Interface o2) {
        System.out.println(o1.getType().getCode()+" : "+o2.getType().getCode()+" > "+o1.getType().getCode().compareTo(o2.getType().getCode()));
        return o1.getType().getCode().compareTo(o2.getType().getCode());
    }
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think the intent was to sort in-place.